# Can't parse JSON string returned because it adds the data type to the JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a basic AJAX function that calls a PHP script and the script returns a **perfect** JSON string, I have checked it.

Here's what the AJAX code looks like:

```
function onLoad() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/api.php",
        data: {symbol: "MSFT"},
        async: true, 
        dataType: 'text',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        success:  function (data) {
            console.log("data is: "); 
            console.log(JSON.parse(data)); 
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log("There was an error");
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
    }); 
}
```

Here is what the php code looks like:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(0);

$symbol =$_GET['symbol'];

$data = array("year" => 2018);
$data_string = json_encode($data);


function grabHTML($function_host_name, $url)
{

$ch = curl_init();
$header=array('GET /1575051 HTTP/1.1',
    "Host: $function_host_name",
    'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
    'Connection:keep-alive',
    'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4)         
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36',
    );

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR,$f = fopen(__DIR__ . "/error.log", "w+"));


    $returnHTML = curl_exec($ch); 

if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}   
   curl_close($ch);
    return $returnHTML; 

} // end of function grabHTML

$url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=" . $symbol . "&from=2018-10-29&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=0cc1ee750c69497899f81b14d32dfbf9";

$results = grabHTML("newsapi.org", $url);

echo $results;
```

However, at the front end, the data type gets pre-pended to the JSON string, i.e.

```
string(17484) " (perfect JSON string here) "
```

So another " gets appended to the end of the data. This crashes the JSON.parse() function.

I have tried all  "dataType: 'text'", "dataType: 'html'", and "dataType: 
'json'" and it still adds the data type every time.

I need to stop it from adding the data type.

Brent.

Comment: if you are not parsing the data, just log the data, whether the response has the string(1784) ?

Comment: Hi Dileep, I tried console logging the data with *brent* at the front and back, and it put out *brent* string(17484) " (JSON string) "*brent*  So it's not the console.log that is putting the data type in there.

Comment: isn't it possible to get rid of the prefix `string(17484) "` and suffix `"` by using some js substring routine?

Comment: can you copy paste the response

Comment: string(1015) "{"status":"ok","totalResults":1,"articles":[{"source":{"id":null,"name":"Diariomotor.com"},"author":"David Clavero","title":"Probamos el Opel Insignia diésel de 136 CV: en la era SUV, una berlina sigue teniendo mucho sentido","description":"En plena fiebre SUV prueba una de las berlin…","url":"https://www.diariomotor.com/noticia/prueba-opel-insignia-diesel-consumo/","urlToImage":"https://www.diariomotor.com/imagenes/2018/10/opel-insignia-prueba-1018-001-mdm.jpg","publishedAt":"2018-10-28T09:22:33Z","content":"En p ventas las berlin… [+4736 chars]"}]}"

Comment: i think you are parsing the entire response, can you just take the articles property, like JSON.parse(data).articles, that will give you the entire articles array

Comment: can you share the php code as well, to understand, how the JSON response on your API side is working. Issue can happen at server side as well.

Comment: Hi Dileep, you can't do that because it won't parse in the first place.

Comment: Jacob, I put the PHP code above.

Comment: try setting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);` in your php script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false); 
In the PHP script.